# positive elements of $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a abelian $C^*$-algebra and $a,b$ are elements in $A$ such that
 $0‎\leq ‎a‎\leq ‎1,0‎\leq ‎b‎\leq ‎1‎‎$ then $0‎\leq ‎a‎b\leq ‎1‎$.

My problem is:" Is it true if $A$ is not abelian?"

Comment: No. In fact, $ab$ may even not be self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Typical example is $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, 
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ b=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\ 1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $0\leq a\leq 1$, $0\leq b\leq 1$, but neither $ab$ nor $ba$ is selfadjoint.